# Reverse Puzzling

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, reverse-puzzling

George is a great puzzler, so I was extremely surprised when he didn't immediately know the answer to a really famous puzzle.  It's a puzzle that you probably did years ago, and have heard so often you can do it from memory rather than working it out.  It's also not really that difficult, so I was also surprised when it appeared to be stumping him.

"Come on, surely you know this one." I said.

"I don't.  And don't call me Shirley." He answered grumpily.  I could tell his mood was declining rapidly, but like any great puzzler he was down and not out, and I watched his facial expression change as he reached into his mental bag of tricks. He nodded towards a conveniently located white board. "Have you got a marker for that?"

I handed him one, and he drew up the following diagram:

[image: Reverse FCB]

He stepped back, admiring his work, beaming proudly. "Well, now the solution is very obvious!" he commented.

And indeed it was.

The question for you is:

> what was the puzzle?

Comment: 42! …wait, no, hold on…

Comment: I've actually learnt something from this. I'd never thought of how to do a formal proof for this puzzle so now having seen the answer I reckon I can solve any puzzle of this type. :)

Comment: This is a really neat idea!

Comment: @Chris For your benefit http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18/learning-to-solve-a-river-crossing-puzzle#answer-326 , altough it seems like you've already worked it out from the graph above :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf: Yup. That pretty much confirms my method. As somebody comfortable with graphs like this the moment I realised what the above diagram represented I realised how to extend it. Nice to see confirmation that there is nothing that I missed though. :)

Comment: I assume C*|FC is a typo for B|*FC?

Comment: Fixed the typo...@DrunkWolf, nice link - someone's already done everything!

Comment: I think I found another typo - B*|FC should be B|*FC

Comment: Thanks @kingofzeal. Fixed. They were of course deliberate to make the puzzle harder ;-).  For the record, in my head they were (F)ox, (C)hicken and (B)ag of corn, which is how I saw it phrased [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/a-man-a-chicken-and-a-fox).

Comment: What I like about the solution is that you can easily **see** the puzzle in the diagram. `|` is the "R****" (hide spoiler), `*` is to the left of the R on the left side, and right on the right side; other combinations on each side relate to allowed combinations, and it does become quite logical. The links are what is can look like after each connection. As @Chris pointed out, makes solving these sort of things in the future quite a bit easier :)

Comment: I could have made it harder by having R for R++++ and M instead of *, I suppose. I totally overestimated how hard this would be.

Comment: @DrXorile AH! BAG of corn. My initial answer had a sack of Corn and Chicken; I had to make one of the C's turn into a B.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't know if the puzzle has an established name, but it should be something similar to this:

> A man has to get a Fox, a Chicken, and a sack of Barley across a river.
>  
>  He has a rowboat, and it can only carry him and one other thing.
>
>  If the fox and the chicken are left together, the fox will eat the chicken.
>  
>  If the chicken and the barley are left together, the chicken will eat the barley.
>
>  How does the man do it?

.

> All nodes in the graph represent all the LEGAL states in the puzzle (where nothing can eat anything else). Each line between each pair of nodes represents a single move (i.e. the man crossing the river).

.

> F represents the Fox, C represents the Chicken, B represents the Barley, * represents the man, and | represents the river.

The puzzle starts at the top left node, and the goal state is at the bottom right node.

> (On second thought, the reverse could be true as well, if the man starts on the right side of the river instead.)

Comment: This doesn't explain connection between FB*|C and C*|FC. And what is C*|FC at all?

Comment: @klm123: A typo for B|*FC.

Comment: Congratulations!  You were extremely quick on this.  I was hoping that it would be a bit more baffling.  Glad to see that it was an enjoyable puzzle though - I'll have to think about similar ones...

Comment: @DrXorile Thanks for the puzzle! It was really enjoyable and I was super fortunate to have visited the site the second you posted the question :P I think what made it easier was your insistence that it was a famous puzzle - that instantly narrowed it down quite a bit :)

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me like:

> You (represented by `*`) have a fox (`F`), cat (`C`) and a bird (`B`) which you have to get over a river (`|`).  and there's an error `C*|FC` should be `B|*FC`

Comment: Foxes eat more birds then cats I think..

Comment: @DrunkWolf Not if it's a Tweety-like bird in a cage with a Sylvester-like cat and just a plain fox that can't open cages :) )