# Reverse Puzzling 8 - Another Chess One with an Allumwandlung

Tags: chess, reverse-puzzling

[Continued thematically from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111477/reverse-puzzling-7-i-fed-the-circus-some-dam-gas)]

George grinned at the sight of the chess board. "What have we here?"

"This was the first two-mover to show [Allumwandlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allumwandlung) using only this many pieces," I explained.

"Allum what now?" It was rare to flummox George, but before I could answer he said, "Oh, I guess you're going to promote that pawn into different pieces."

"You got it. This is the first one: **White to play and mate in two**."

George studied the board for a moment and then said, "f8=♗, and it's mate next move. Only one line."

"Now for the second one," I said. "**Back to the original position and move the white queen to a7.**"

Again George took just a moment: "f8=♖, and it's mate next move. Only one line."

"Now for the third one," I said. "**Back to the second position but move the black King to c6.**"

George was in the swing of it now: "Easy. f8=♕."

"Very good. Last one," I said. "**Back to the third position but move the *white* King to c4.**"

As you will have guessed, this was answered by f8=♘.

> What was the original position? Bonus points for the original author of the puzzle.

Tip:

> Work backwards...

Comment: Guessing, promotion to a knight might fare the only advantage over promotion to a queen.

Comment: @humn, there are circumstances where promoting to a Bishop or Rook is better. This puzzle provides these examples. It is a "good" puzzle in the sense that there is only one solution for each of the four variations. It would be artificial to promote to a B or R when promoting to a Q would also win. In other words, each promotion is the only way to solve the "mate in two" part of the puzzle.

Comment: Is "mate in two" invalidated if it's mate in one?

Comment: @Ausername, yes. It must be mate in exactly 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Board State:

> [image: picture of board]
>
>  FEN: 8/5P1Q/4k3/8/4K3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
>  After `... Kf6`, white has `Qf5#`

After moving White's Queen:

> [image: mate with rook]
>
>  After `... Kd6`, white has `Rf6#`

Note:

> In both of the previous two positions, promoting to a Queen is stalemate.

After moving Black's king:

> [image: mate with queen]
>
>  Pretty straightforward checkmate

After moving White's king:

> [image: mate with knight]
>
>  After the only legal move, `... Kd6`, white has mate with `Qc5#`
>  Note that promotion to Queen or Bishop ends in stalemate, and promotion to a rook can only force mate in 3!

Comment: Excellent. Only a minor correction on the first position. Qg7 is not mate because Ke6

Comment: Oops! Good point, it seems I got this correct for the wrong reasons - editing now for posterity, thanks for the catch!